# Cron job failed on Google Cloud

Tags: flask, cron, google-cloud-platform, yaml, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to add the scheduled tasks in my server deployed on Google Cloud using [the cron functionality](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron). Before deploy, I'm testing in localhost, so I've configured a simple cron.yaml file like this:

```
#cron file
cron:

- description: Testing cron functionality
  url: /task
  schedule: every 1 minutes
```

And a simple endpoint like the following:

```
#myblueprint.py
#from ... import ....
from app.exceptions.sql_exceptions import (NotFoundException, InvalidValueException)
from fga.frameworks.flask.core import BeforeRequestFlow

tasks_bp = flask.Blueprint('task', __name__, url_prefix='/task')

@tasks_bp.route('', methods=['GET'])
def new_or_list():
    logging.info("++++++++++++++++++TEST CRON++++++++++++++++++")
    return flask.Response(
            response="Cron ejecutado correctamente",
            status=201
        )
```

So I run my server on localhost and I've entered into the Development SDK page that simulates the gCloud environment. In the Cron Jobs section my task appears and also the countdown to execute it but when the count goes to 0 then the task is not executed.

Only it's executed when I press the button Run Now and it appears in my console the desired debug message. Why?

[image: Manual execution of the cron task due to I've clicked on the Run Now button]
*Manual execution of the cron task because I click on the **Run Now** button*

Answer (score 2):

The development server doesn't run cron jobs. This is a long time missing feature.

Comment: Thanks for the info, do you know the source of this "bug"?